# Is there a way to change div color on validation error?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been working on a contact form with validation. Im using constraint validation api, and I have these files which kinda works the way I want, but I wonder if there's a way I can make the errorboxes red when there's an error, and white (or hidden) when there's no validation error. There's probably some code which is unneccesary, and I plan to clean it up when i'm satisfied with the functionality, but now it looks like i have errors everywhere when everything is valid.

```js
const form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
const email = document.getElementById('mail');
const emailError = document.querySelector('#mail + span.error');
const navn = document.getElementById('navn');
const navnError = document.querySelector('#navn + span.error');
const telefon = document.getElementById('telefon');
const telefonError = document.querySelector('#telefon + span.error')
const message = document.getElementById('message');
const messageError = document.querySelector('#message + span.error')
const personvern = document.getElementById('personvern');
const personvernError = document.querySelector('#personvern + span.error')


// THIS DIV WILL CONTAIN ERROR MESSAGES
const errOutput = document.querySelector('.errorsOutput')


email.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
  if (email.validity.valid) {
    emailError.innerHTML = '';
    emailError.className = 'error';
  } else {
    showError();
  }

});


navn.addEventListener('input', function(event) {

  if (navn.validity.valid) {
    navnError.innerHTML = '';
    navnError.className = 'error';

  } else {
    showError();
  }

})

telefon.addEventListener('input', function(event) {

  if (telefon.validity.valid) {
    telefonError.innerHTML = '';
    telefonError.className = 'error';

  } else {
    showError();
  }

})


message.addEventListener('input', function(event) {

  if (message.validity.valid) {
    messageError.innerHTML = '';
    messageError.className = 'error';

  } else {
    showError();
  }

})

form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {

  if (!email.validity.valid || !navn.validity.valid || !telefon.validity.valid || !message.validity.valid) {
    showError();
    event.preventDefault();
  }

});



function showError() {

  // EMPTY ERRORS DIV
  errOutput.innerHTML = ''


  if (navn.validity.valueMissing) {
    navnError.textContent = '* Du må fylle inn navnet ditt';
  } else if (navn.validity.tooShort) {
    navnError.textContect = '* Du må fylle inn hele navnet ditt'
  }
  // OUTPUT ERRORS IN DIV

  if (navnError.textContent != '') {
    errOutput.innerHTML += '<p>Navn error!</p>'
  }

  if (email.validity.valueMissing) {

    emailError.textContent = '* Vennligst fyll inn e-posten din';
  } else if (email.validity.typeMismatch) {

    emailError.textContent = '* Dette er ikke en gyldig e-postadresse.';
  } else if (email.validity.tooShort) {

    emailError.textContent = `* Email should be at least ${ email.minLength } characters; you entered ${ email.value.length }.`;
  }
  // OUTPUT ERRORS IN DIV
  if (emailError.textContent != '') {
    errOutput.innerHTML += '<p>Email error!</p>'
  }



  if (telefon.validity.valueMissing) {
    telefonError.textContent = '* Du må fylle inn telefonnummeret ditt'
  } else if (telefon.validity.tooShort) {
    telefonError.textContent = '* Du mangler ett eller flere tall. Vennligst dobbeltsjekk.'
  }
  // OUTPUT ERRORS IN DIV
  if (telefonError.textContent != '') {
    errOutput.innerHTML += '<p>Telefonnummer error!</p>'
  }

  if (message.validity.valueMissing) {
    messageError.textContent = '* Beskjeden mangler, vennligst fyll inn'
  } else if (message.validity.tooShort) {
    messageError.textContent = `* Beskjed må være minst ${ message.minLength } tegn.`;
  }
  // OUTPUT ERRORS IN DIV
  if (messageError.textContent != '') {
    errOutput.innerHTML += '<p>Beskjed error!</p>'
  }
}


// Set the styling appropriately
emailError.className = 'error active';
navnError.className = 'error active';
telefonError.className = 'error active';
messageError.className = 'error active';
personvernError.className = 'error active';
```

```css
body {
  width: 600px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}

p * {
  display: block;
}

input[type=text] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  min-width: 500px;
  width: 100% !important;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 90%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=email] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  min-width: 500px;
  width: 100% !important;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 90%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=tel] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  min-width: 500px;
  width: 100% !important;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 90%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* This is our style for the invalid fields */

input:invalid {
  border-color: #900;
  background-color: #FDD;
}

input:focus:invalid {
  outline: none;
}


/* This is the style of our error messages */

.error {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  min-height: 20px;
  font-size: 100%;
  color: white;
  background-color: #900;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.error.active {
  padding: 0;
}

.errorsOutput {
  background-color: #ac0606;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}

.errorsOutput p {
  padding: 1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="kontaktskjema.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="kontakt.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Kontaktskjema</title>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- THIS DIV WILL CONTAIN ERROR MESSAGES -->
  <div class="errorsOutput">
  </div>

  <div class="kontaktskjema">
    <div class="error">
      <form novalidate>
        <p>
          <label for="navn">
          <span>Navn:</span>
        <input type="text" id="navn" name="navn" required minlength="3">
        <span class="error" aria-live="polite"></span>
      </label>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="error">
      <form novalidate>
        <p>
          <label for="name">
            <span>Telefonnummer:</span>
            <input type="tel" id="telefon" name="telefon" required minlength="8" required maxlength="8">
            <span class="error" aria-live="polite"></span>
          </label>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="error">
      <form novalidate>
        <p>
          <label for="mail">
                <span>E-post:</span>
                <input type="email" id="mail" name="mail" required minlength="6">
                <span class="error" aria-live="polite"></span>
              </label>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="error">
      <form novalidate>
        <p>
          <label for="message">
                    <span>Beskjed:</span>
                    <input type="text" id="message" name="message" required minlength="10">
                    <span class="error" aria-live="polite"></span>
                  </label>
        </p>
    </div>
    <form>
      <p>
        <label for="personvern">
                      <div class="personvern">
                      <span>Personvern:</span>
                      <br>
                      <input type="checkbox" id="personvern" name="personvern" required>
                      <span>Jeg har lest og godkjent <a href="https://demo2108.mobilpluss.no/ac/personvern">Personvernserklæringen</a></span>
                      <span class="error" aria-live="polite"></span>
                    </div>
                    </label>
      </p>

      <button>Send</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <script src="kontakt.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: the easiest way to achieve something like you wish and without screwing your logic could be to modify your showError function in a way that it will add a css class (styling the parent and its children) to the container holding the field having validation error. But your code is very too much specific and requires too much efforts to show you in practice. In general: `element.classList.add('classname')`. By the way there are errors in your code going beyond wrong logic... there's wrong syntax also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I'd do it, is through application-defined element attributes.

CSS totally support [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). If you set some attribute of the `div` element to a certain value, say `data-validation-error=true`, then in your CSS

```
div[data-validation-error="true"] {
   /* red */
}

div[data-validation-error="ok"] {
  display: none; /* hidden */
}
```

and in JavaScript, use the `setAttribute` function on the div you want to control.

Notice I used the `data-` prefix. This is the standard HTML attribute prefix for user/application-defined attributes.